# Javascript save settings to one or more cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

On a blog I am working on, I use a cookie to save a user preference on which side of the layout that the sidebar should show, so I have a cookie something like this...

name: `sidebar_switcher`
value: `right` or `left`

No wI just built a Modal/screen overlay DIV that shows on users first visit, I made it set a DIV once this Modal window is hidden/closed so that I don't nag the user on every visit with it.  SO I now have another cookie being saved like this...

name: `subscribe`
value: `yes` or `no`

So my question, since each Cookie is a new HTTP request as far as I know, should I instead be storing these values into 1 cookie?  If that is the case, then should I do it as a JSON string?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* store it as one cookie, or you could use `localStorage()` with a fallback on cookies.

That way, your users with modern browsers don't need to parse any cookies around.